# Formula for The Voltage of a Coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I've seen 2 different formulas being used for the voltage of a coil in a circuit. The first one is $$U_L=L\cdot\dot{I}$$ and the second one is $$U_L=-L\cdot\dot{I}$$ The first formula was used in a circuit with a resistance and a coil, to calculate the total voltage as $$U_0 = U_R + U_L$$ and the second formula has been used everywhere else so far.
I'm not which formula I should use in which context. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of AC circuits, voltage on an element means usually "decrease of electric potential along the pre-chosen positive direction". For an *ideal* inductor (one without ohmic resistance), this potential drop is always with + sign:
$$
p.d. = L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$

This result is because for a path through an ideal inductor, the effect of the potential drop completely cancels out the effect of the induced electromotive force $\mathscr{E}_i$, which is known (both for ideal and real inductors) to be given by
$$
\mathscr{E}_i = - L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
The minus sign here is to express correctly the Lenz law: the induced electromotive force in such direction that it acts to prevent the change of current.